# Adding new facet to DSpace has no effect (DSpace 4.1)

Tags: facet, discovery, dspace

I changed the discovery.xml file as described in the documentation to add a new facet over dc.type to our DSpace. When I finished reindexing and deleting the cache I see the new search filter at advanced search but not as a facet.

These are the changes I made to discovery.xml:

Added filter to sidbarFacets and SearchFilter:

```
<ref bean="searchFilterType" />
```

and this is the filter:

```
<bean id="searchFilterType" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilterFacet">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="type"/>
    <property name="metadataFields">
        <list>
            <value>dc.type</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifications to discovery.xml on the latest DSpace master branch worked on my local setup:
https://github.com/bram-atmire/DSpace/commit/3f084569cf1bbc6c6684d114a09a1617c8d3de5d

One reason why the facet wouldn't appear in your setup, could be that you omitted to add it to both the "defaultconfiguration" as well as the specific configuration for the DSpace homepage.

After building and deploying, a forced discovery re-index using the following command made the facet appear:

```
./dspace index-discovery -f
```

Comment: Great that's the solution, it's working now. I did't get that from the documentation. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example facet that I have configured in our instance.  Try setting the facetLimit, sortOrder, and splitter.  Re-index and see if that resolves the issue.

```
<bean id="searchFilterGeographic"
    class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.HierarchicalSidebarFacetConfiguration">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="geographic-region"/>
    <property name="metadataFields">
        <list>
            <value>dc.coverage.spatial</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="facetLimit" value="5"/>
    <property name="sortOrder" value="COUNT"/>
    <property name="splitter" value="::"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer I added `<property name="facetLimit" value="5"/>` and `<property name="sortOrder" value="VALUE"/>` but it had no effect. Any other suggestions?